# How to change button css on pageload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css

Hi and thanks in advance...

I have a button that I want change the css on pageload in c# and asp.net. Right now, on pageload, I am only able to change the text. When the text contains "ADD" I need it to be green, else blue.

Inside of a gridview I have this:
ASP.NET

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tower">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button_Detail" CssClass="page-btn blue" CausesValidation="false"
                                        CommandArgument='<%#Eval("idRangeList") %> ' CommandName="Detail" runat="server"
                                        Text='<%# getButtonText(Eval("idRangeList")) %>' OnClick="btnDetails_Click">
                                    </asp:Button>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

c#

```
protected string getButtonText(object o)
{
    String btnText;
    int rID = Convert.ToInt32(o);

    WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

    var text = (from t in context.Towers
                where t.isDeleted == false && t.fkRangeList == rID
                select t);

    if (text.Count() == 0)
    {
        btnText = "3. ADD";

    }
    else
        btnText = "Details";


    return btnText;
}
```

I am up for either a jquery or c# solution.

I have tried both and I am stuck. On the C# side, I am not able to access the ButtonID.

For JS I tried this, but its not doing anything:

```
function textCheck() {

 //var buttonDetails = $("Button_Detail");

 if($("Button_Detail:contains('ADD')")){
     $("Button_Detail").css("green v2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the function in my asp page in question and added an alert and nothing popped up. I also tried my site master page with the same results.

Comment: So I took the alert out of the function, which now works. But I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

you need to try:

```
 if($(".page-btn").val()=='ADD'){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass('.page-btn green');
 }
```

Comment: I did this, but did **val()=="3. ADD"** I noticed something very strange, here it won't work, but if I change it to **val()=='Details'** it works. I am confused. Also I assume there isn't a contains method.

Answer (score 0):

This line will not work:

```
$("Button_Detail").css("green v2");
```

It needs to be:

```
$("Button_Detail").addClass("green v2");
```

However this will still not work as your selector isn't correct. It either needs to have a `#` for IDs or a `.` for classes. Given that .NET's IDs are changable it's far easier to give your control a unique class and use that.

In your case:

```
$(".page-btn").addClass("green v2");
```

The jQuery `css` function is for adding specific CSS properties to an element.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

If you want to manipulate which classes an element has you should look at the class attribute documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Comment: I think your right about .NET IDs. Using firebug, I saw it was changed to this: id="MainContent_GridView_Button_Detail_2"

Comment: I don't think my function is loading. I put an alert in there and nothing is happening. Do I need to call it from somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you need to call it for it to work. Where it is called from will depend on what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: Well I as soon as the user goes to this particular page, I want it to be called. Doesn't have to be use on any other page. So this is why I don't think using the site master is a good idea. So I guess right now, how to I call the function when I user opens this particular page.

Comment: I had to add this in c# pageload:                                        **ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:textCheck(); ", true);**